# Filling in columns with a function

Tags: r

I have a dataset called population. The first column the year, second is the population, and third is the death. How do I add a column that gives percent of people who died that year? (death*100/population) in R.

Comment: `population$percent <- population$death * 100 / population$population`

Comment: When I do that an error comes up saying "non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: This error could occur for a number of reasons. Please provide a sample of your data.